# Installing Azure Powershell error after installation

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Good Morning,

I was trying to install Azure powershell to connect to my server. I made sure I was up to date on all my versions. Then I ran the: Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobber command. Everything downloaded perfectly and was unzipped successfully.

*Then I know I have to load the AzureRM module so I ran the command: Import-Module -Name AzureRM

*After I ran the command nothing happens! I press ENTER but I just get brought down one line like the command does not even exist.

*I ran the (get-command -module azurerm).count and it showed count of 0.

**So from what I gathered it downloaded/unzipped/installed/but will not actually load?

*To make more sense I followed the instructions from the following youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Q0jG1Doa-s&t=181s

**Any help will be greatly appreciated. Trying to install it to be able to change email names for office 365. Thanks!

PS: I made sure I have version 5.0 of power shell

Version Of Powershell Picture

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7ffr.jpg

[Blanks I get after running command. (nothing happens!)]

: https://i.stack.imgur.com/td9Jv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance you had the AzureRM module installed already, either open a new Powershell session or run...

```
Import-Module -Name AzureRM -Force
```

To double check the module was installed correct, enter...

```
Get-Module -Name Azure*
```

Ensure the version is what you want.

When I install AzureRM on a fresh machine, I do...

```
Get-Module -Name PowerShellGet -ListAvailable | Select-Object -Property Name,Version,Path
Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force
Install-Module -Name AzureRM -AllowClobberso
Import-Module -Name AzureRM
```

This worked for me on a fresh Windows 10 15063-build.

Comment: Thank You for the quick response it says it is installed!

Comment: Kewl. Then you should be good, and to clarify, you'd need to run "$(Get-Command -Module AzureRM*).Count" (not the module name change) to get the command count. What you have won't return anything even if the module is installed.

Comment: Amazing just tried it and I got 2040 count! I am beyond excited about this breakthrough. lol. Out of curiosity, In the video link i posted he wrote out the command how I entered it in the original post and it worked for him. Any idea why? just being a curious hippo here.

Comment: No idea. I'd ask the video's author.

Comment: If this answered your question, mark it as the answer.